# What's the difference of a Zabbix Event and a Zabbix Problem?

Tags: zabbix

In Zabbix there are events.
I understood that triggers can create events which then can cause problems.

What's the relation between events, problems and triggers?

Answer (score 2):

A Trigger can generate a problem event, or a resolution event. A non resolved problem event is a Problem.

There can be

- trigger events - whenever a trigger changes its status (OK→PROBLEM→OK)
- discovery events - when hosts or services are detected
- autoregistration events - when active agents are auto-registered by server
- internal events - when an item/low-level discovery rule becomes unsupported or a trigger goes into an unknown state

see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/events

Comment: The important part was when you provided the definition "a non resolved problem event is a Problem". Because this is very confusing naming by Zabbix.